# jQuery: Automatically submit form only after submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a regular form, when the submit button is clicked I want to hide the submit button, and if any form values change after submitting it'll auto submit again.

I'm using the following code and it works, but each time I update the form data and the form is automatically submit, in the JS console I can see it's being submit many many times, and the number increases each time it auto submits. e.g. first auto submit posted once, second auto submit posted 4 times, third auto submit posted 8 times and then the form starts getting really slow due to this.

```
jQuery(function($) {

$(document).on("click",'#bookingbutton', function() {
    $( "#bookingbutton" ).css( "display", "none" );
    $( ".bookroom1" ).addClass( "bookroom1-submit" );

    $(".bookroom1-submit").change(function() {
        $("#bookingbutton").click();
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because each time you call `$("#bookingbutton").click()` you are registering again a `change` listener in `.bookroom1-submit`.

Try replacing

```
$(".bookroom1-submit").change(function() {
    $("#bookingbutton").click();
});
```

With

```
$(".bookroom1-submit").off('change').on('change', function() {
    $("#bookingbutton").click();
});
```

That should do it.

**EDIT**

Some further explanation on the problem:

1. Submit button is clicked.
2. It adds a class to the button and registers a `change` listener.
3. Next time, when an input changes, you are triggering a click on the button, which will cause 1. and 2. to happen again. Now you will have 2 listeners for `change`.
4. it will continue to grow exponentially.

Another alternative is, instead of `$("#bookingbutton").click();` use `$("#your-form-id").trigger('submit');`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explaination!

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery off and then one:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
      $(document).off("click", '#bookingbutton').one
      ("click", '#bookingbutton', function () {
          $("#bookingbutton").css("display", "none");
          $(".bookroom1").addClass("bookroom1-submit");

          $(".bookroom1-submit").change(function () {
              $("#bookingbutton").click();
          });

      });

  });
```